# php - Decide whether an image exist and if it does show it

Tags: php, image, conditional-statements

I have a code that shows a different image depending where on the page I am, but some places don't have an image so it displays a "no image" icon. I want to add a condition that checks if there really is an image in the given path and if returns false don't do anything. I have no idea how to do it.

This is the original code:

```
<?php
$search=get_search_query();
$first=$search[0];

if ($first=="#"){
      echo "<html>";
      echo "<img src='http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/".substr(get_search_query(), 1). ".jpg'>";
}
?>
```

What I need to know is which function do I use to get a true/false of that image path. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file_exists`

```
$image_path = 'Imagenes/grupos/' . substr(get_search_query(), 1) . '.jpg';

if (file_exists($image_path)) {
    echo "<img src='http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/".substr(get_search_query(), 1). ".jpg'>";
} else {
    echo "No image";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)